# Why can't I create a bootable Win7 flash by simply dd'ing the .iso to /dev/sd*?

Tags: dd, iso

It so happens that I need to install Win7 on a PC with a brand new blank HDD  (the old one failed). I have the needed .iso file (on my Android tablet) and the only place I can stuff a USB flash into is my ASUS router ;)
I presumed that if I simply telnet into my router (the .iso is on another flash) and perform

```
umount /dev/sdc
dd if=ru_windows_7_home_premium_with_sp1_x64_dvd_u_676728.iso of=/dev/sdc
```

then it should create an exact copy of the iso with MBR and all, regardless of what OS is there. But no such luck: after dd completes (it takes quite a while) the USB is unbootable and unreadable. What am I doing (or thinking) wrong?

Comment: Remember that while your bios might be able to boot any media it likes (USB, CD, HDD) the thing installed on that media (windows installer) also needs the right drivers in all the right places to read from the media.  If the windows bootloader is intended for a CD, it might not understand what a USB stick is.

Comment: I like the idea of installing Gnu/Linux, and Virtual Box, and putting MS-Windows in the box. It is easier, and safer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1> make your thumb-drive a linux-live drive (same procedure you said before)
2> boot your computer from that live linux
3> use your PC disk drive to burn 'windows' ISO onto a DVD
4> restart your pc with DVD in

Or easier:

1> Call a friend and ask to use his pc to burn your 'windows' dvd
2> start your pc with new dvd in
3> launch windows setup
4> offer a beer (or some vodka) to your friend and enjoy
5> reboot your PC

again:
1> Make a 'live linux usb' (same as 1st way)
2> Install linux on your pc
3> Install Virtualbox
4> Install windows into virtual machine

Comment: Wow, that sounds brilliant - I'm off to google up "linux-live" and where to get one ;)

Comment: I would have used the "easier" way if I were not down with a flu ;) Don't really want to leave home with a fever.

Comment: Get well soon! 123

Comment: Must be still doing something wrong - got a Slax .iso (first to come up in search), used the same dd command (took much less time as Slax is much smaller than Windows) but still the PC won't boot off it and the router won't mount it..

Comment: `dd bs=4M if=input.iso of=/dev/sdc conv=fdatasync` Also check the distro you downloaded is UEFI-compatible

Comment: Trying with bs=4M (did not know it was important) and fdatasync is not supported by the tiny Linux stub running on the browser. I am giving it generous time to finish and make sure the LEDs stopped blnking. As for UEFI-compatible, I will look into it but first I want to make sure that the flash drive is at least mountable by the router itself. If it's not then I guess it doesn't make sense trying to boot from it...

Comment: It's the OS distro you choose that has to be bootable. bs=4M will force dd to use 4MiB chunks instead of 512B (it should improve performances) conv=fdatasync tells dd to sync data at the end (if it doesn't I suggest you to reboot 'politely' your router with reboot command or using the web UI)

Comment: Also check on PC that boot trough USB is enabled and thet USB is checked at boot-time (usually pressing `<esc>` or `<del>` or `<F12>`)

Comment: Tried with bs=4M, rebooted the router politely to flush cache - no success so far. The PC is def bootable from USB and it sees it and offers to boot from it but can't. But what bothers me is that the resulting flash drive is unmountable and unreadable by the router itself - it should be, right?

Comment: Have you disabled secure boot on your PC? I also suggest you to set it into 'legacy' mode

Comment: Checked and tried absolutely everything - still no success. I might have damaged the flash drive when moving it between router and PC (had to remove it from its bulky casing so that it even fits into the router along with the other flash drive) or I might be making some stupid glaring error somewhere. Will make a pause for now. I hugely appreciate the time you spent on me - I learned a lot which is maybe more important than making that damn PC boot ;) If you are ever in Moscow - the beer is on me (or vodka;)

Comment: You're welcome. Anyway, if I'Il ever get there you'll know. (A promis is promis). I suggest you to try with this version of CentOS (I'm sure it has uefi support): ftp://mirror.awanti.com/centos/7.6.1810/isos/x86_64/CentOS-7-x86_64-LiveGNOME-1810.iso

Comment: Tried it with your CentOS and it worked flawlessly! Burning the DVD right now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

There are strange dependencies between file-systems, and storage media, in both MS-Windows, and PC firmware boot-loaders.

ISO images are for CDs, not usb-storage. Some ISO images are hybrid, but not all.

Comment: As for file systems, I presumed that dd would write on a lower level, wiping out whatever file system was there before and creating the whatever file system is part of the iso file. Your second point must be the reason - the problem is I have no idea how to check or make it "hybrid". There are articles on creating Win7 bootable flash drives on Linux, they all involve custom GUI software that obviously won't run on my router... Apparently this software exists for a reason and there is no easy way.

Comment: ISO 9660, is a file-system, for CDs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660